# How can I access the internal storage on a device with adopted storage

Tags: root-access, external-sd, twrp, adoptable-storage

For my tablet I have TWRP on it and it can't access the sd card as it is encrypted. I need to put some files on it to flash with TWRP. How can I access it? I have magisk so I can do root options

Comment: you can *adb push* some small files to */cache* partition (or memory */tmp*)